# reveal hidden div

Tags: html, css

hi i am try to reveal the content in my div para2 when the user clicks the more img link

i have used this code before and it worked but i wont now ??

Please point out my mistakes i am only a beginner

thanks in advance

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
        <a href="#para2"/>
        <a href="#" onclick="return toggleMe('para2')" onfocus="#para2"/> <img src="images/more.gif" alt="" title="" border="0"></a>  
        <div id="para2" style="display:none"> 
            text i want to reveal 
        </div>
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

sorry

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function toggleMe(a){  
        var e=document.getElementById(a);  
        if(!e)return true;  
        if(e.style.display=="none"){  
            e.style.display="block"  
        }  
        else{  
            e.style.display="none"  
        }  
        return true;  
    }  
</script> 
</head>
```

Comment: I think it would be nice see source code for toggleMe function

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Where is your toggleME() function defined? what does it do exaclty? Perhaps you could post a simple .html file (with js and css embedded) or a link that we can open to observe your code? Also does your javascript console in the browser show any errors?

Comment: It appears to work. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kolink said onfocus is wrong. Try something like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/gL37n/5/

Answer (score 1):

`#para2` is not a valid piece of javascript code, so you can't use it as an `onfocus` attribute.

Since you're getting a syntax error there, it is possible that it's breaking out of the `onclick` code as well, therefore not running it.

Try removing the `onfocus` attribute, and see if that fixes it.